# Cypress interactions commands race condition

Tags: cypress

When I try to, for example, click on a button using Cypress, the **get** command will get the button before it is actionable (still invisible for example). The **click** command later will fail because the subject passed to it is not actionable. How to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Please add the code that you tried.

Comment: cy.get('#button').click();

Comment: the point is that get fetches the button from the DOM before the button is visible, and the click gets an invisible subject to click so it fails. I thought about overwriting the click command and other actionable commands, but is it the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a visibility assertion

```js
cy.get('#button')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click();
```

Comment: This worked fine for me, but since the problem is scattered all over the tests, I thought about overwriting the click command to make it do the assertion before clicking if the force option is not true. The same approach could be followed with other actionable commands as well.

Comment: Is it really worth it, more code, more things to go wrong. Plus you might need other checks under different conditions - so more mods to the commands. The above is simple and well used, I try to avoid too many custom commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `visibility` check as well as make sure the button is `enabled` and then perform a `click()`.

```js
cy.get('selector').should('be.visible').and('be.enabled').click()
```

I won't suggest you to overwrite an existing cypress command, instead create a custom command under `cypress/support/commands.js` like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('waitAndClick', (selector) => {
  cy.get(selector).should('be.visible').and('be.enabled').click()
})
```

And in your test you can add:

```js
cy.waitAndClick('button')
```

Comment: This does not seem like good practice to me.